# Angular UI Router Redirecting to Abstract state with parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states.

```
.state('workflow2', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/workflow/:workflow_id',
    views: { 
        'main': { 
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/view_workflow.html', 
            controller: 'view_workflow' 
        },
    },
    resolve: { authenticated: authentication }
})

.state('workflow2.view', { 
    url: '/view', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/workflow/view.html', 
    controller: 'workflow.view', 
    resolve: { authenticated: workflow_item_auth }
})
```

I'd like to be able to redirect my user to:

> /workflow/**:workflow_id**/view

I've tried the following but keep getting the following error because I have `abstract :true` enabled:

> Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'workflow2'

```
$state.go('workflow2', {workflow_id: id});
$state.go('workflow2.view', {workflow_id: id});
```

Does anyone know how I can redirect a user to my "view" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.state('workflow2.view', { 
  url: '/:workflow_id/view', 
  templateUrl: 'pages/templates/workflow/view.html', 
  controller: 'workflow.view', 
  resolve: { authenticated: workflow_item_auth }
})
```

Comment: Yup :) it is I appreciate the help, will click the check mark once the timer lets me